# The current directory is invalid on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8

I've been trying to run the any of the following command through command prompt as administrator

```
netstat -a -b
sfc /scannow
```

However I get the following error

```
The current directory is invalid.
```

I tried to follow http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257996 but I don't think mine has anything to do with Logon Scripts

**UPDATE**

The output I get after running `set` in command prompt

```
ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData
APPDATA=C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Roaming
CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files\Common Files
CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files
CommonProgramW6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files
COMPUTERNAME=MUSTAFA-PC
ComSpec=C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe
FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO
HOMEDRIVE=C:
HOMEPATH=\Users\Mustafa
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_25
LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local
LOGONSERVER=\\MicrosoftAccount
NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=8
OS=Windows_NT
Path=C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Windows Performance Toolkit\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor;C:\Program Files (x86)\Universal Extractor\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Compiler Runtime\v715\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;D:\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC
PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE=AMD64
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 58 Stepping 9, GenuineIntel
PROCESSOR_LEVEL=6
PROCESSOR_REVISION=3a09
ProgramData=C:\ProgramData
ProgramFiles=C:\Program Files
ProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)
ProgramW6432=C:\Program Files
PROMPT=$P$G
PSModulePath=C:\Windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\
PUBLIC=C:\Users\Public
SystemDrive=C:
SystemRoot=C:\Windows
TEMP=C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Temp
TMP=C:\Users\Mustafa\AppData\Local\Temp
TOMCAT_HOME=D:\tomcat7.0.39
USERDOMAIN=MUSTAFA-PC
USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE=MUSTAFA-PC
USERNAME=Mustafa
USERPROFILE=C:\Users\Mustafa
VBOX_INSTALL_PATH=C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\
windir=C:\Windows
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Have you changed directory before trying the commands?

Comment: Nope. I tried from both `C:\>` and `C:\Windows\system32>` but I get the same error message.

Comment: Do you get the error on both commands?

Comment: Yes I get the error on both

Comment: run procmon in background while running the command and filter the RESULT column for the "invalid directory" error. Now look if you see some details: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor

Comment: I did as you suggested but after setting up the filter I don't see any result filtered.

Comment: Type `set` in the command prompt, press Enter, and post the full command output here.

Comment: I just updated my question with the output given after running the `set` command. Thanks